# Can I create PDFs to portray 2D orthographic drawings from a series of coordinates defined in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, pdf, drawing, autocad

I am creating an app which allows a user to create simple models of engineering components. I have the coordinates of the geometry in the form of Vector3s and was hoping to reconfigure this script into a series of 2d orthographic drawings to a given scale (e.g. 1:5, 1:10, etc.) as a vector PDF. I have tried looking into how AutoCAD does this and handles other levels of information such as lineweights and corner-style (bevel, mitre). Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You can use different cameras to get the shots you need and export what is being rendered... You can also use materials on the models to highlight line information, depth etc...

Comment: So if I have an Orthographic camera looking down from above (for example to create a plan) how can I export that as a PDF to a set scale (e.g. 1:5)?

Comment: You would first need to acquire the rendered image as a texture and then you can do whatever you want with it. I would first go about exporting it as an image (.jog for example) and then try to experiment with scales and different file formats.

Comment: That is one option.. Although I need the orthographics in a vector format, not a bitmap. I'm looking into a solution to recreate a CAD plotter - taking coordinates from the list of Vector3s and feeding them into list of cartesian coordinates to write a PDF file in PostScript. Many thanks for your ideas though! Perhaps I can use some Image Tracing techniques to convert the bitmap back into a vector??